# How to ignore Deleted columns in excel sheet while iterating over cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a POI application ***version-3.17***. My excel sheet has several rows and 14 columns initially. I want to iterate over the cells of each row and put the cell-values into a **Map**. In the sheet, some cells have **NO values**. And afterwords, I deleted **8th & 10th columns** also for not required. So there are 12 columns as of now in the sheet.

But My problem is, while iterating over the cells of a row, it's getting 14 values instead of 12. I guessed the deleted 8th and 10th columns are also including in the iteration. I don't know why.

Below code I used,

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
...
```

Also I tried with,

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
...
```

but result is same.
I checked that `row.getLastCellNum()` is returning 14, instead of 12.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You seem to delete the columns after reading the values and not before. If you don't want to read the columns, delete them first

Comment: Weird, how about `Sheet.isCollumnHidden`?

Comment: I tested after deleting the columns, but it's the same. There no hidden column i checked @Joop Eggen.
I got one solution, which is not very convenient, but its working for me. I replaced all the empty cells with string "null" and handled it through code.
Now I'm getting 12 columns, not 14.

Comment: Try following [one of the other ways of iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) that gives more control of blank cells?